# Attributing effect of independent variables on time series data

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, arima

Consider a response variable, say, sales of a company. This variable is time series data (confirmed by using ACF and PACF plots). The sales depend on other variables such as price of the product, marketing spends in different channels, etc. If I use ARIMAx modeling technique to regress sales on itself (previous values of sales), pricing, and marketing spends- will the beta values associated with pricing and marketing give me their true contribution? If not, how do I attribute the effect of independent variables on a time series data? I am not really concerned with predicting the future values of sales- the objective is to attribute sales to pricing and marketing spends..